# How to turn off logging from SLF4J?

Tags: java, logging, jakarta-ee, slf4j

It's a third party application generating huge amounts of log entries on our app server. Like this:

```
[03.03.10 15:21:57:250 CET] 00000180 FtpProtocolHa I org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter info Close connection : 10.227.10.10 - admin
[03.03.10 15:27:35:209 CET] 00000181 MinaFtpProtoc I org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter info [/10.227.10.10] CLOSED
++++
```

How do I turn this output from SLF4J off? I've looked in the .war file to find some configuration for SLF4J but nothing. Their website didn't help either.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

slf4j is just a funnel to the actual log backend (here overriding jakarta commons logging), which is the one you must configure to get rid of a certain kind of messages.  For logback this is the appropriate configuration snippet which goes in your `logback.xml` configuration file:

```
    <!--  No Tomcat debug logs -->
    <configuration>
    ...
        <logger name="org.apache.catalina.core" level="OFF" />
    ...
    </configuration>
```

For log4j it is very similar.

Comment: Where is this snippet supposed to go?

Answer (score 15):

Alternatively, download http://www.slf4j.org/dist/slf4j-1.6.4.tar.gz, look in there for slf4j-nop-1.6.4.jar (this is the no-operation logger) and include this in your classpath. When the SLF4J classloader sees this (it looks to see what loggers are in the classpath that it can use), it **should** stop logging (once you've restarted the app).

At least this way you don't need to mess with the log configuration files...

Comment: On my system I had to also remove slf4j-log4j*.jar from my classpath.

Comment: slf4j will dislike intensely if you have more than one slf4j backend in the classpath.

Comment: I am using maven, I added the dependency that Mr Zorn suggested, I changed other slf4j dependencies to all have the same version, as Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen suggested, but I am still seeing the logs from the external library.

Answer (score 4):

As stated by [@sparkyspider answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748518/8583692), you can simply add the **slf4j-nop** library to your application.

If using Maven, add this to your *pom.xml* file:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.36</version>
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

If using Gradle, add this to your *build.gradle[.kts]* file:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.36")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

slf4j is a logging facade for various logging frameworks. That output comes from the Apache Commons Loggin framework adapter, that turns to be another facade. [Commons Logging Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/logging/guide.html#Configuration).

Answer (score 3):

Which logging back-end, e.g. logback, log4j, j.u.l., are you using? You need to configure the backend to filter those messages.

Moreover, the fact that the log messages point to "`org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter`" indicates that caller location inference is *not* working correctly. (It should mention the actual caller not `JCLLoggerAdapter`). This can happen if:

1. you are using an older version of SLF4J

or

2. the caller is using a slf4j-like wrapper or has its own homegrown logging API which does not infer caller location properly. See also a relevant [SLF4J FAQ entry](http://slf4j.org/faq.html#optional_dependency).

Comment: This is a third party application. I don't have access to any code (other than decompiling) There are no log4j.properties files or any other files that look like they containt any log-properties

Answer (score 0):

Search for the following string: `level="DEBUG"` using your **IDE**.
You will find that text in a **.xml** file.

Go there and use `level="INFO"` instead of `level="DEBUG"`.

The key value is not case-sensitive.

There can be something like:

```
<root level="info">
    ...
</root>
```