# Azure Java SDK: How to disable logging to console?

Tags: java, azure, maven, azure-java-sdk

I'm developing an application using **Azure's Java SDK** and **Maven**. This application sends data to an IoT Hub and some other functionalities that are not important for the scope of the question.
I implemented my own logging inside the application by using `log4j2` and I'm fine with that since I can modify and change it however I want.

The problem arose when I checked this warning that was coming up in my application's console output:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Thanks to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder) I was able to do the correct move and add the dependency inside my `pom.xml` file like so:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.project.myProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
...
```

After this addition the Azure's SDK started printing to console a lot of information that I don't really want to see. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.customlogger?view=azure-java-stable) should be the class that originates the logging.
Following, some output that gets written to console by itself.

```
...
Jun 07, 2018 8:09:18 PM com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.CustomLogger LogInfo
INFO: IotHubConnectionString object is created successfully for iotHub.azure-devices.net, method name is <init>
Jun 07, 2018 8:09:19 PM com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.CustomLogger LogInfo
INFO: DeviceClientConfig object is created successfully with IotHubName=iotHub.azure-devices.net, deviceID=device01 , method name is <init>
Jun 07, 2018 8:09:20 PM com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.CustomLogger LogInfo
INFO: DeviceIO object is created successfully, method name is <init>
Jun 07, 2018 8:09:20 PM com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.CustomLogger LogInfo
INFO: Setting SASTokenExpiryTime as 2400 seconds, method name is setOption_SetSASTokenExpiryTime
...
```

I've already tried to disable the `Logger` but with no success (followed [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372056/how-to-turn-off-logging-from-slf4j)).

I would like to know if someone has ever had this problem and if so how can I disable the logging features or else suppress the warning?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a blog [`How to Configure SLF4J with Different Logger Implementations`](https://dzone.com/articles/how-configure-slf4j-different) which you can refer to to configure your `slf4j-jdk14` logger implementation, as below.

> **Using slf4j with JDK logger**
>
> The JDK actually comes with a logger package, and you can replace pom.xml with this logger implementation.
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
>   <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
>   <version>1.7.5</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> Now the configuration for JDK logging is a bit difficult to work with. Not only need a config file, such assrc/main/resources/logging.properties, but you would also need to add a System properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties in order to have it pick it up. Here is an example to get you started:
>
> ```
> level=INFO
> handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
> java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINEST
> deng.level=FINEST
> ```

There are two ways to avoid outputing these `INFO` logs to console.

1. Upgrade the logging level from `FINEST` or `INFO` to `WARNING` to `SEVERE`, you can refer to the Oracle Javadoc for class [`Level`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html), as below, then to not output low level logs.

> The levels in descending order are:
>
> ```
> SEVERE (highest value)
> WARNING
> INFO
> CONFIG
> FINE
> FINER
> FINEST (lowest value)
> ```

2. To change the `handler` value in `logging.properties`. Except `ConsoleHandler`, there are four other handlers which you can use, as below, please see [`java.utils.logging`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) package summary.

> - ConsoleHandler: This Handler publishes log records to System.err.
> - FileHandler: Simple file logging Handler.
> - MemoryHandler: Handler that buffers requests in a circular buffer in memory.
> - SocketHandler: Simple network logging Handler.
> - StreamHandler: Stream based logging Handler.

For example, to output logs to a file

```
handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=INFO
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=1024000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=10
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=logs/mylog.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.append=true
```