# How to stop Azure Blob Java SDK TransferManager printing "WARNING: SLOW OPERATION..."

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

I use the azure-storage-blob v11.0.0 sdk in my java project.

To download blobs from my blob storage I use the following code.

```
final BlockBlobURL blobURL = containerURL.createBlockBlobURL(blob.getName());
            AsynchronousFileChannel fileChannel =
                    AsynchronousFileChannel.open(
                            localFile.toPath(),
                            StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                            StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
            ResponseTracker responseTracker = new ResponseTracker(
                    TransferManager.downloadBlobToFile(fileChannel, blobURL, null, null).doAfterTerminate(fileChannel::close).toFuture(),
                    fileName);
```

But whilst downloading files sometimes I get this output.

> WARNING: SLOW OPERATION. Duration > 3000 ms.
> Request try:'1', request duration:'8417' ms, operation duration:'8417' ms
> GET: https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxxx/this%2Fin2%2FoneGBImages7.zip?sv=2017-04-17&ss=bf&srt=co&spr=https&se=2020-07-10T12%3A44%3A41Z&sr=co&sp=racwdlup&sig=REDACTED
> Content-Length: 0
> x-ms-version: 2018-11-09
> x-ms-range: bytes=784334848-788529151
> host: xxxx.blob.core.windows.net
> connection: keep-alive
> If-Match: 0x8D824056357EBBF
> x-ms-client-request-id: xxxxx-ac90-47c8-85fa-34e172a7cd47
> User-Agent:  Azure-Storage/11.0.0 (JavaJRE 13; MacOSX 10.14.6)

I'd like to disable this in some way. I can't find anything on the net on how to disable this. I'd rather not block all logging from the storage sdk.

Any ideas on how I can suppress this output?

Comment: Could you please tell me if you download this file successfully?

Comment: Yes, the files downloads successfully, it's just it prints this message which I wish to suppress.

Comment: I would check out this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54554782/azure-java-sdk-how-to-disable-logging-to-console

Comment: But I don't want to block all logging, just this one.